# VueJs no animation trigger on variable classname

Tags: css, vue.js, css-animations

I have a VueJs component and 2 classes with animations.
I have a v-bind:class on a div, but when the class changes, the animation doesn't run.
When the update_page computed property changes, the class changes as well.
What am I doing wrong?

The div:

```
<div
        class="top-0 right-0 bottom-0
          absolute h-full bg-primary"
        :class="update_page ? 'detail-header-hide' : 'detail-header'"
      ></div>
```

The css class:

```
.detail-header {
    width: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 1500ms;
}

.detail-header-hide {
    width: 100%;
    animation: fadeIn 1500ms;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    60% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know snippet looks bad, but i mean problem will be at reusing one animation. Try to add one more to your project like me at snippet ('fadeOut')

```js
let x = document.querySelector('div')
function toggle(){
  x.classList.toggle('detail-header-hide')
   x.classList.toggle('detail-header')
}
```

```css
.detail-header {
    width: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 1500ms;
}

.detail-header-hide {
    width: 100%;
    animation: fadeOut 1500ms;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    60% {
        width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    60% {
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div
        class="detail-header-hide"
      >Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</div>
      <button onClick='toggle()'> btn </button>
```